# Using “domination of” to show skillfulness

Tags: word-usage

Can “domination of” be used to show skilfulness?

Examples:

1. Sarah has a great domination of mathematics.
2. He has a high domination of plaing piano.

Comment: What did you find when you looked domination up in the dictionary, and why didn't that help you?

Comment: We speak of *mastery* of skills and fields of endeavour, not *domination*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use domination to show that someone is so much better than others, but not in the manner you have shown.

*His work dominated the art scene last year.*

*Our team dominated throughout the game.*

http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/dominate